# javamail can't read sum mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a class with here i read my email (gmail) 
code of my class

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "mail@gmail.com", "pass");
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
    Message messages[] = inbox.search(ft);
    for(Message message:messages) 
    {
        Multipart parts = (Multipart)message.getContent();//line 26
        Object p = parts.getBodyPart(0).getContent();  
        String q = p.toString();//object has the body content  
//code
}
```

but i have this problem

```
    SEVERE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet Login a généré une exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart
    at pack.Testmail.<init>(Testmail.java:26)
    at pack.Login.doGet(Login.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try using (just suggestion, Not sure it will work for your case): `Multipart parts = new MimeMultipart(); BodyPart bodyPart = parts.getBodyPart(0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular message is apparently not a multipart message.

https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getContent()

> Return the content as a Java object. The type of the returned object
>   is of course dependent on the content itself. For example, the object
>   returned for "text/plain" content is usually a String object. The
>   object returned for a "multipart" content is always a Multipart
>   subclass. For content-types that are unknown to the DataHandler
>   system, an input stream is returned as the content This is a
>   convenience method that just invokes the DataHandler's getContent()
>   method

You can check the part's MIME type to see what kind of content it has.

```
if (message.isMimeType("message/rfc822")) {
    Message message = (Message) part.getContent();
    ...
}
else if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
    Multipart mp = (Multipart) part.getContent();
    for (int i = 0, max = mp.getCount(); i < max; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
else if (message.isMimeType("text/*")) {
    String text = (String) part.getContent();
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: tnk for comment but how i can result this problem pls?

Comment: It probably won't be long before you need more help from the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html/att).  You'll also find some sample code to download on the [JavaMail project page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).